# How to start a detached tmux session via ssh?

Tags: ssh, tmux

I know I can start a detached tmux session like this:

```
> tmux new -d -s mysession sleep 10000
> tmux ls
mysession: 1 windows (created Mon Apr 16 22:56:14 2018) [177x62]
```

Now I want to start it via ssh:

```
> ssh some_user@some_host_name tmux new -d -s mysession sleep 10000
```

It just fail silently without any output.

And on the server side I only get

```
> tmux ls
no server running on /tmp/tmux-1000/default
```

How can I get it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tmux needs a pseudo terminal to run.  Add the -t option to ssh like this

```
> ssh -t some_user@some_host_name tmux new -d -s mysession sleep 10000
```